# Transfer set in tuple to array in CPLEX?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, tuples, cplex, opl

```
{route} Routes ={
<1,{1,3},{8,5}>,
<2,{2,3},{7,9}>
};
```

Can I extrat the last set in the two tuple as 2D array with the first tuple as index from `Routes`? If the index doesn't show in the first matrix, give it 0 in the matrix

Which means,

```
Arr=[
[8,0,5],
[0,7,9]
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about where to insert the '0' in each case. But of cause if you can formulate the rule precisely a program can perform it. So give it a try, post your code and where exactly you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
tuple route
{
key int r;
{int} s1;
{int} s2;
}

{route} Routes ={
<1,{1,3},{8,5}>,
<2,{2,3},{7,9}>
};

sorted {int} indexes1={i.r | i in Routes};
sorted {int} indexes2=union (i in Routes) i.s1;

int res[i in indexes1][j in indexes2]=(j in item(Routes,<i>).s1)
    ?item(item(Routes,<i>).s2,ord(item(Routes,<i>).s1,j))
    :0;

execute
{
writeln(indexes1);
writeln(indexes2);
writeln(res);
}
```

gives

```
{1 2}
 {1 2 3}
 [[8 0 5]
         [0 7 9]]
```